# How can i change the style of a radio button in XAML/C# for metro app?

Tags: c#, xaml, radio-button, microsoft-metro

I'm trying to change the style of a radio button in XAML/C# for a metro app, but i can't find any information about how to do that.
I want my radio button to be bigger and centerd when i big up the text.
Any help or code examples would be great.

Comment: did you try to change style/template?

Comment: Yes great, thank you. I didn't know you can change the templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to edit the template of your control.

You can do it with Blend, or "by hand".

Retrieve the default template of your radio button and then customize it in order to fit to your needs

EDIT : [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751600%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is MSDN Ressource on `RadioButton` template customization.

EDIT2 : All default templates can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773.aspx)

Comment: where the radio button default template is located?